# Simple OpenRefine IF to create a new column

Tags: openrefine, grel

Im trying to create a new column which contains true or false. Basically column A has a number in it, between 1 and 6, if its higher than 3 I want the new column 'match' to contain true, otherwise it contains false. Using the add column based on column in trying the following GREL

```
if(value > 5, "True", "False")
```

That basically results in EVERYTHING being false.

I know my IF statement is correct because the following works

```
if(value.length() > 1, "Double", "Single")
```

Im just confused why if Value is greater than 5 doesnt work, its obviously missing something but I cant seem to pinpoint it in the docs.

Comment: Are the values in the column formatted as numbers and not as strings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your GREL if() is correct. Our docs for that are here:
https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Controls

But I wonder if you really have all number values in that Column ?
Are all the values "green" color ?
If not, try using Edit Column to Trim Whitespace and then convert the Text to Numbers.
Then try your if() on that column again and see what happens.

Comment: Alternatively you could modify the GREL to include this step (leaving the original column as a string) - if(value.toNumber() > 5, "True", "False")

Comment: ahh, I just presumed as it was a number it was treated as numeric, but it was being treated as a string. Used edit cells to trim whitespace (no cells changed), then used the common transformation 'to number'.  Data was imported from a csv out of a database where it was numeric. Now my numers are 'green' and the equation works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if(value.toNumber() > 5, "True", "False")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.